# why method for signing url for AWS CloudFront is not working when deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (500 Error)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, private-key, signed-url

I and my colleagues are developing Spring Boot project for study purpose. We use AWS S3 as cloud storage for storing images. Aslo we decided to use AWS CloudFront as content delivery network for retrieving images and use a CloudFront origin access identity (OAI) to access the S3 bucket. For this purpose our server generate signed url using ssl private key and keyPairId.
Code look like this:

```
    @Value("${cloud.front.distribution.domain}")
    String distributionDomain;
    @Value("${cloud.front.key.pair.id}")
    private String keyPairId;
    @Value("${cloud.front.private.key.filePath}")
    String privateKeyFilePath;

    try {
           return CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy(SignerUtils.Protocol.https,
              distributionDomain, new File(privateKeyFilePath), fileName,
              keyPairId, calendar.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't generate signed URL", e);
        }
```

Everything worked just fine when I am using localhost but when project is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk it gives 500 Error.

I was thinking that problem is that file with private key is located in static directory and it can not be read at deploy stage. But relocating to other place doesn't helped. It is hard for me understand in what direction I have to search.

Comment: Error 500 is not really descriptive. maybe your Spring boot application allows displaying errors to the webpage for debugging purposes? If not, you should look into the log files on the server to see what the exception is that your application runs into.

Comment: @MaxVisser thanks. In log file I found `Mar 29 16:44:17 ip-172-31-22-208 web: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/static/galleryPrivateKeyPk8.pem (No such file or directory)`. Could you advise where I should put the private key, so it can be recognized ?

Comment: Hi Roman, if i read your use case why would you not directly connect over local network with s3. You can add an iam role to the eb instance and use the java aws sdk and some environment variables to connect.

Comment: Normally i would suggest putting your private keys in an s3 bucket and using a predeploy hook to retrieve then from s3.

Comment: @MaxVisser thanks for answer. The reason why eb is not directly connected to s3 is that we don't want to download images first to server and then transfer to frontend. We thought that it would be more effective to return only url for downloading to frontend. We are new to all AWS tools, so maybe we are doing smth strange. And am I right, that you advice me to do with private key this ?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html

Comment: Hi Roman, Yes thats a good example. Another example is this for a .env file:
https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/master/.ebextensions/00_copy_env_file.config

Don't forget moving the private key to the right location:
https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/23524d112398720a2759ab13076a98f2203b1b1f/.ebextensions/01_deploy.config (line 18)

Answer (score 0):

I would store your private key in a S3 bucket which you retrieve on app deploy.

You can do this by creating an `.ebextension` for example `00_copy_private_key.config` which uses the instance role attached to the EC2 instance to safely connect to a s3 bucket containing your private key.

```
# Replace `elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-xxxxxxxxxxxx` with the bucket that AWS created
# when you created your first Elastic Beanstalk environment.

# Make sure that the IAM Role for the EC2 Instance set in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration
# has attached the `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` policy.

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

# From the created bucket, point to the .env file which you want to
# copy to this app during deployment.

# The file will be copied first in /tmp/.env, then moved to the app
# in the deployment process.

files:
  "/tmp/private.key":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-xxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/private.key
```

source:
https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/23524d112398720a2759ab13076a98f2203b1b1f/.ebextensions/00_copy_env_file.config

After copying over the private key you still need to move it to the right location where you app expects it:

```
container_commands:
  00_copy_private_key:
    command: "mv /tmp/private.key /var/app/staging/private.key"
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for help. As for now reached  Error web: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/pki/tls/certs/gallery_private_key_pk8.pem (Permission denied). Above described situation. Maybe you have some thoughts for this ?